# Docusign listBatch

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I have a list of envelopes that works fine with liststatuschanges, but I would like to exclude the envelopes that belong to batch (which are currently also appearing in the list of envelopes), to make a separate list for batch only.
Is there any way to exclude those envelopes that were sent within a batch from my envelope list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it requires to you mark them before you send them in the batch.
For example, you can use custom text fields and when you set your bulk send (what you call batch) you can set this custom field. You can later search for envelopes based on custom fields values. You can also use other metadata.
The envelopes sent from batch are indistinguishable once they were created from any other envelopes, just like envelopes created from templates are. You have to mark them yourself to be able to later find them.

Comment: and to get a batch list similar to your docusign interface, what is the correct method?

Comment: I posted another question with the code, it returns null according to the method in the documentation.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/bulk-send-envelopes/ did you follow this?

Comment: Im able to do bulk send, but the list batch acording to your method result null to me, except if I pass some Id , var option = new BulkEnvelopesApi.GetBulkSendBatchesOptions
            {             
                status = "all",
                count = numberOfItems.ToString(),
                batchIds = "XXXXXXXXXX",
            };                                      the model in view is IEnumerable<DocuSign.eSign.Model.BulkSendBatchSummary>

Comment: you need to pass the batchId, you get that when you create the batch

Comment: To have a list of batches, I have to pass the batchId of eachone?

Comment: I mean, you have to go through the list first to get each BatchId, and then get the Batches list, isn't there another way?

Comment: I'm confused, not clear what you're trying to do. Sorry.

Comment: I posted my question with the method GetBulkSendBatches to get a list of Batches but it returns null

Comment: Did you try to get the batchId when you inmate it? one at a time?

Comment: Like thisone its ok                                                                                                        
 var options = new BulkEnvelopesApi.GetBulkSendBatchesOptions
            {
                status = "all",
                count = numberOfItems.ToString(),
              batchIds = "88b08888-74b0-4683-9fd2-xxxxxx, f1897948-ccb2-45ed-b708-xxxxxxx",

            };
            IEnumerable<BulkSendBatchSummary> listeBatchs;
            listeBatchs = bulkEnvelopesApi.GetBulkSendBatches(accountId, options).BulkBatchSummaries;

Comment: we can see both of them batches in the list, but its not supposed to passed them(BatchId), its not required according documentation, just accountId for GetBulkSendBatches method or there is something that I'm missing ?

Comment: You probably mean to use https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/bulkenvelopes/bulksend/getbulksendbatchstatus/ and not GetBulkSendBatches. The one I send you is for a single batch with a batchId. The one you pointed out is for many batches, not sure why you would need this one.

Comment: yes, a Batches List thats what I want

Comment: But getBulkSendBatchStatus need BatchId is required, when I did the envelopes List for ListStatusChanges its not required (envelopeId, just accountId), what is the similar to do a list of batches?

Comment: Otherwise I have to store a list of batchId in a database, every time I do a bulk sending, to use it later to get the batch list. Is it like this or can I get the BatchId of each of the lines of my batch list with another method?

Comment: yes, if that's what you need to do - you'll have to store the batchId in a database. Not sure this scenario is otherwise supported.

Comment: ah ok, because for the list of envelopes with ListStatusChange it was not needed

Comment: thank you very much, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Yes, not the same, envelopes and batches

Comment: thank you, thats what i did, now its ok
Inbar Gazit, when the signer  complete the sent document, a docusign login page is showed to invite user to create an account or to login, how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can simply store batch id when u use bulk send api, once you store, you can fetch all envelopes using code below

// C# Code
  var bulkEnvelopesApi = CustomApi.Instance.BulkEnvelopes(accessToken, basePath);
            var batchStatus = await bulkEnvelopesApi.GetBulkSendBatchStatusAsync(accountId, batchId);

  if (batchStatus.Failed.Equals("0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && batchStatus.Queued.Equals("0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && !batchStatus.Sent.Equals("0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var bulkSendEnvelopes = await bulkEnvelopesApi.GetBulkSendBatchEnvelopesAsync(accountId, batchId);

                return bulkSendEnvelopes?.Envelopes;
            }
```